# Access to webcam in browser?

Tags: silverlight, flash, html, video-streaming, video-capture

For an internal project we would like to play with building a video conferencing system. We are able to decide the browser that the user has to use and can install plugins.

The only requirement is that the browser and plugins must be free and work over Linux and Mac. (Don't care about Windows)

What is the best way to do access the webcam and mic stream from a user for sending to a server?

Ideally I would like to do this plugin free but I can see no implementation of the devices tag in HTML5 in any browser yet, unless someone knows different.

If its flash/silverlight, any quick examples of capture and sending to a server?

Also any examples of streaming video from a server to a client would be useful, so we can stick it all together. This I know we can do in HTML5 so this would be a preference.

The client connection part is all I would need as we are building the server, this is the internal challenge.

Basically I'm looking for good examples and best practices for sending and receiving this information.

**Edit:** *As I have discovered from some groups the device tag is no where near completion. So answers will have to be flash/silverlight (does that work on linux??).
See a demo of device tag done on a webkit custom build: https://labs.ericsson.com/blog/beyond-html5-conversational-voice-and-video-implemented-webkit-gtk*

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Red5 project. I think that it is what you're looking for. The examples are quite good.
http://red5.org